# What are the axes of a t-SNE scatterplot?

Tags: probability, distributions, scatterplot, tsne

What do the values in the x axis and y axis of this scatterplot correspond to? It is related to t-SNE but I don't know how.

[image]

The plot is from:

- Lingren T, Chen P, Bochenek J, Doshi-Velez F, Manning-Courtney P, Bickel J, et al. (2016) [Electronic Health Record Based Algorithm to Identify Patients with Autism Spectrum Disorder](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0159621). PLoS ONE 11(7): e0159621. doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0159621

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'm going to add this to my library of examples of poor graphing practices.

Answer (score 5):

t-SNE is a technique for visualizing high-dimensional data in a low-dimensional space (2- or 3-dimensional). It attempts to preserve local structure: in other words, points that are close (according to some metric) in high-dimensional space remain close in the new, low-dimensional space.

The mapping between the high-dimensional and low-dimensional space isn't simple, however. It's computed using an iterative procedure (for details, [see here](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/publications/papers/JMLR_2008.pdf)), and it ends up being highly nonlinear.

This isn't surprising; a linear mapping wouldn't help with dimensionality reduction. Quoting from the paper,

> Traditional
> dimensionality
> reduction
> techniques
> such
> as
> Principal
> Components
> Analysis
> (PCA;
> Hotelling,
> 1933)
> and
> classical
> multidimensional
> scaling
> (MDS;
> Torgerson,
> 1952)
> are
> linear
> tech-
> niques
> that
> focus
> on
> keeping
> the
> low-dimensional
> representations
> of
> dissimilar
> datapoints
> far
> apart.
> For
> high-dimensional
> data
> that
> lies
> on
> or
> near
> a low-dimensional,
> non-linear
> manifold
> it is
> usually
> more
> important
> to
> keep
> the
> low-dimensional
> representations
> of
> very
> similar
> datapoints
> close
> together, which
> is typically
> not
> possible
> with
> a linear
> mapping.

Anyway, all of this is a long-winded way of saying that the axes of a t-SNE plot aren't easily interpretable in terms of the axes/units of the original, high-dimensional data. So I wouldn't try to interpret a t-SNE plot quantitatively; t-SNE is just a visualization technique, nothing more.